# Stack overflow - static memory vs. dynamic memory

Tags: c++, stack, stack-overflow

If you write `int m[1000000];` inside the main function of C/C++, it will get a runtime error for stack overflow. Instead if you write `vector<int> m;` and then push_back 1000000 elements there, it will run fine.

I am very curious about why this is happening. They both are local memory, aren't they? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a max array length limit in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216259/is-there-a-max-array-length-limit-in-c)

Comment: What do you mean by "local" memory?

Comment: Your question is asking about "C/C++", but you can't write vector<int> in C. "vector" is a C++ class that hides the complexity of the underlying memory management.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the vector itself is an automatic (stack) object.  But the vector holds a pointer to its contents (an internal dynamic array), and that will be allocated on the heap (by default).  To simplify a little, you can think of `vector` as doing `malloc`/`realloc` or `new[]` calls internally (actually it uses an [allocator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator)).

EDIT: As I noted, automatic variables are allocated on the stack, while `malloc` generally allocates on the heap.  The available memory for each are platform and even configuration-specific, but the available stack memory is typically *much* more limited.

Comment: you forgot to explain the size limitations of heap vs. stack. malloc / realloc / new are all dandy, but they don't actually explain anything..

Comment: @matthew-flaschen : This might be slightly unrelated but I have a problem around it. Now If i want to provide custom allocator for these classes and which will be of different sizes (for sure), I have to use placement new and override the new / delete. Now the normal memory managers gets fragmented, so i have posted a question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920453/custom-memory-allocator-manager-in-c-which-approach.

Comment: @ianmac45, the question was whether they were both "local memory".  As I explained, `vector` uses heap ("non-local") memory.  I'll elaborate on the size issues.

Answer (score 6):

The amount of stack memory is limited, because it has to be reserved in advance. However, the amount of heap memory will typically expend up to much higher limits imposed by your OS, but "nearly" reaching the limits of your virtual address space (2GB for a 32-bit machine, a whole lot more for a 64-bit machine).

You can increase the amount of reserved stack space, typically as a setting to  your linker.

Comment: You forgot to mention that this is system-specific.  On GNU/Linux, you can use `ulimit -s` to increase the stack size right before executing.

Answer (score 5):

int m[1000000] - It will **allocate the 1000000 ints on stack**. as stack is limited so it will throw the stack overflow runtime error.

vector m; and then push_back of 1000000 elements are working because **internally vector allocates the memory on heap not on stack**. so in your application stack only the vector object is present so it is not throwing the stack overflow runtime error.

Answer (score 1):

The vector object itself is on the stack; but internally it will allocate memory from the heap as needed to store an arbitary number of elements.  So the stack cost is small and fixed for it.